# How do I continually update my gps coordinates in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gps

Im creating a react native app that has built in methods for grabbing my longitude and latitude coordinates. I'm using an android for this.

I't works fairly randomly, even though i am using a setInterval. Sometimes it only responds when I'm moving around, and sometimes it will update properly even when I'm not moving.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


class Geolocation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

   this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null
    };

   setInterval(this.location.bind(this),3000)
  }

 location(){
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        let obj = {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null
        }
        this.setState(obj);
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000},
    );
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.location()
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
  }

 render() {
    return (

             <View style={{ position: 'relative', top: 70, flexGrow: 1, 
alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
              <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
                {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
             </View>

    );
  }
}

export default Geolocation;
```

Again my problem is the location doesn't update properly, I've tried on both wifi and my phones 4g data and no change.

How do I make the location coordinates update regularly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `getCurrentPosition` and not `watchPosition`?

Comment: I tried `watchPosition` first but wasn't even getting the coordinates to pop up, so i switched to `getCurrentPosition`. I tried using `watchPosition` with a `distanceFilter` to update every 10 meters and without it to no avail. how would you use `watchPosition` in this context?

Comment: If `watchPosition` was what you really wanted to do, then *you should be asking a question about whatever issue you ran into there*. Your current code and question doesn't really make sense unless there's a special reason you are trying to use `getCurrentPosition` in conjunction with `setInterval`. The behavior you're describing - *"Sometimes it only responds when I'm moving around, and sometimes it will update properly even when I'm not moving."* - is **exactly as expected** as you are simply checking for the position every 3 seconds.

Comment: Also, you are also clearing the `watchID` which is not needed with `getCurrentPosition`; it's only needed with `watchPosition`.

Comment: I'll switch it back and test `watchPosition` , do you think `setInterval` becomes redundant with `watchPosition`

Comment: Yes. If `watchPosition` is working as intended (works in the app I'm building), then there isn't a reason to use `setInterval`.